Conditioning Column Formatting based on Date and entry in another Column
I am completely new to this and am trying to create a Register in Sharepoint.
Basically what I want to do is:

If the date in Column 1 is coming up in the next 5 days, I want to change the font to orange
If the date in Column 1 is overdue, I want to change the font to red
If the date in Column 2 is not empty, do not format Column 1 (basically, remove the formatting  in Column 1 once Column 2 is filled).

Context: Column 2 is the date the action in Column 1 is completed.
I tried using Co-Pilot to help me with JSON and it came up with the following but it doesn't seem to work:
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$COLUMN2] != '', '', if(@currentField <= @now, 'red', if(@currentField <= @now + 2592000000 && @currentField > @now, 'orange', 'green')))"
  }
}

Can I please get some guidance?
Thanks!

Try this JSON and make necessary changes if required.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(Number([$Date2]) != 0, '', if(@currentField <= @now, 'red', if(@currentField <= (@now + 432000000) && @currentField > @now, 'orange', 'green')))"
  }
}


@Vee711 - Please accept and upvote this answer if it is helpful to you. Thanks.
